# Long battery lifetime light? (LED etc.)

Tags: led, low-power

I design some plastic models, and I would like to include a small light (LED or similar). I am looking for a solution with a long battery lifetime. I'm not a electrical engineer but I read that, for example, 1 Red LED consumes around 20 mA, so with 2x AA batteries it lasts around 210 hours.

Does any solution exist for long life, e.g. for months? I don't need high brightness, it is only decoration for a diorama - for example, as a light in a small model of a house etc.

Thank you for any help.

Comment: You might get away with 1 or 2 mA if you use the right LED.

Comment: the question is how much brightness you need. Generally, a pair of batteries, and a switching step-down converter can get you pretty far, but of course, the brighter, the higher the power consumption. Does your diorama really need to be on continuously for months?

Comment: Thank you! I don`t need a lot of brightness, it is only for "visual effects" in small models. Diorama doesnt need continuously, but if there is a switch, I do not remember turn on/off it. So I look at for solution. 1-2mA LED are great - I do not know that exists.

Comment: Have a look at the "tritiled" project.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some LED's are *very* efficient, and the eye is *extremely* sensitive. In a moderately lit room, a white or blue LED should be clearly visible, though not bright, with just 100 microamps. Two CR-2032 Li cells. [Rated at ~200 mA/hr](http://data.energizer.com/pdfs/cr2032.pdf), this should last >2,000 hours, ~3 months. Put a 30 kilohm (kΩ) resistor in series (or even a higher resistance for a dimmer, but longer lived light). You could also use AA or AAA "penlight" cells (you'll need three or four for a white LED), and they should last a year or more.

The eye is less sensitive to red light, but a red LED can operate from a single Li coin cell. Try 15 kΩ with one Li cell.

A larger resistor decreases current, at the expense of brightness. Try a few different ones for your particular application to find a compromise that looks good on the model and lasts long enough. You might add a switch, but with very large resistors, the battery will last almost as long as if left on the shelf (5-20 years for Li-ion cells).

BTW, in a dark room, one microampere creates enough light to be seen easily.

Comment: If I understand that resistor decrease consumption? Or it is require a "special" low consumption diod? I try "google it" and I found only diods with 2mA as lowest.

Comment: @frosty22 You can run LEDs well below their rated current.  You don't need a special LED to do it.  The resistor controls the current.

Answer (score 0):

You should consider using 2 D size batteries in place of the AAs. I have run a red flashing LED for well over a year hooked straight up to a pair of Ds, no resistor used.

Answer (score 0):

You could take the solar panel from a solar garden light and solder an LED to it. When light hits the panel the LED lights up. No batteries, no switches, it will run a very long time. Or just replace the white LED with a red one.